# Bicycle tire date decode

Tags: tire

I bought a new bike for my 3 year-old. 12.5 inch tires, "yida" seems to be the brand name.

My earlier research suggests that some bike tires have date codes, in the form of circles with an x in it, with either dots and or arrows. I found vintage decoders, which didn't help.

Does anybody know of a good site that has bicycle tire code dates?

Comment: I don't have a useful answer, but note that bike tyres don't suffer the same stresses as car tyres.  So overall ave is much less of an issue.  As long as the bike isn't stored in direct sunlight all the time, you'll get many years of effective use.  Most kids grow out of their bikes long before they wear out the tyres.

Comment: I've never seen any info on this, but, as Criggie states, bike tires can last a long time, so long as they are kept out of the sun and not run flat.  (But note that white tires or white sidewalls are much more sun-sensitive and will tend to start flaking sooner even if kept out of the sun.)

Comment: I think this should be community wiki, as the answer is very likely to be link-only, but we might get several and all of them will be equally useful to someone. Since the question isn't "this date code here", I think it's wiki.